# How to integrate python code into a Website html code?

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-search

For our website backend we are using python coding to search an equipment model on SerpApi, but we are not able to integrate that into our website which is in .html format. Is there any way by which we can integrate that into our website?

We tried integrating it throught flask and pyscript, but not able to get the output result when something is searched in the website. So can we get a way through which we can integrate the python code with html code.

Comment: Your webserver needs to be capable of running python, for a start. Your description of the situation is very vague though so we don't really know precisely what issue you've got, and what steps you've taken so far, what your code looks like, or what result you're expecting. So it's very difficult to help. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your question. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by **integrating**? Do you want python code to be executed on the client side in the browser? Or you want python code to emit your HTML. 

Note: no browser runs python code on its own. Period. 

For the former you need a python interpreter that is browser-enabled: either written in JS or WASM. That is actually possible. 

For the latter, you need a python web framework and a python-capable web server. Or a WASI-capable and compile your python code to WASM code. Or use the python as it's own hosting environment - but I don't recommend that for internet exposed projects.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.